# Anko theme and style

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

Is there a way to add **theme** and **style** to a Layout with Anko? Thanks

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rlHeaderLayout"
style="?defaultStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="?topBarThemeContext">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just Google for same question, and find the answer [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/commit/306d38c22e45dfedaa8a8cd0cd9519c9f31f8599)

#### Themes

Anko support theme override (the xml way is adding `android:theme` parameter >to any view) too by `themed` prefix before any view or layout:

```
kotlin themedLinearLayout(ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark) { 
  orientation = VERTICAL   
  gravity = BOTTOM 
}
```